# i have issue with my database mySQL select from table

Tags: mysql

Dears

Please help me in this matter.

I have issue with my MySQL database.
It is working fine if I'm doing inserting records to the table. However, if I'm doing selecting and fetching, the result is 0 despite of the table actually have records.

```
  $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM `users`';
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
  echo $result2->num_rows;
  if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
      }
  } else {
     echo "0 results";
 }
```

please help me guys I tried every thing I almost give up.

thanks,

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: "not working" how, exactly? That's not an adequate description of the problem by which anyone can help you.

Comment: You need to find an error to pin down the problem. What happens? "Not working" is not a description. "Computer catches on fire" or "the HTML output is missing rows" is.

Comment: sorry for poor description : not working it give me 0 result and i am sure there is content in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this code

```
<?php
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=contoh', "root", "root");
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM `user_ranks`';
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        while($row = $result2->fetch()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];
            $rank = $row['rank'];
        }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "connection or query have a problem: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
```

Comment: i am using this code for configuring


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $config['DB_USERNAME'], $config['DB_PASSWORD']);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: the code has been updated, you can try, i hope this help you